# Twig string to be used in calculation

Tags: symfony, twig

I'm pretty new to Twig.

I'm trying to use a string value to calculate with a variable.
It keeps returning "0" because I guess that the string won't change to an actual value.

So the question is: 
How can you change a string to a variable to be used in a calculation??

So what I have is this:

```
{% if product.price >= 500 and product.price <= 5000 %}

   {% set multiplier = theme.monthly_payment %} {# this is the string #}
   {% set loanValue = (multiplier * product.price) %}

      <span class="loan">
      {{ 'Pay $1 each month' | t (loanValue | money ) }} 
      </span>

{% endif %}
```

So `theme.monthly_payment` is a string with a value of `0,0202`. `product.price` is a variable like `99.95`. 
So what I try to do is to multiply `multiplier` and `product.price` and then later on use `loanValue` to replace a part of string.

Comment: `0,0202` is not a valid numeric representation in `PHP`, so this will be casted to `0`, you should use `0.0202` to make the calculation and `number_format` to display it

Comment: @DarkBee: Ok so you mean I have to do `{% set multiplier = theme.monthly_payment | number_format(4, '.') %}` ?? Can you make an example perhaps? I understand what you mean with the numeric representation. However what do you mean exactlt with `to display it`?

Comment: @DarkBee: Nevermind I found what you said. That works indeed. Thanks for the help!!